# Load Application-Wide Settings During Application Startup from a SQL Server DB Using Entity Framework Core in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

How do I go about getting some data only once (for the entire lifetime of the application until it is turned off or restarted) from a SQL Server database using an Entity Framework Core DbContext during ASP.NET Core's Startup (in my Startup.cs class) of my application? And have that data available for use in my various Controllers?

I have some application-wide settings in a database table that I want to load into memory once and utilize them throughout the lifetime of the application without having to hit the database again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you want to use a method that loads the results on a static property. For example like a list. So a static class like this will do the trick.

```
public static class Settings
{
  public static Dictionary<string,string> Settings {get; set;}
}
```

The code should be placed at the end of Configure. There are 2 ways to do it.

**The Simpler way**

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // your other code

        var yourService = new YourService();
        Settings.Data = yourService.GetData();
    }
```

**The depedency ejection way**

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IYourservice yourService)
    {
        // your other code

        Settings.Data = yourService.GetData();
    }
```

Warning the above method will only work if you are using depedency injection. Generally you want to call those methods when the app has finished configuring. It's a good idea to split the code to different files or/and methods.